# Gradle javadoc hide specified method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, javadoc

is there any way to hide specified method from javadoc if I'm using gradle for generate javadoc?

Right now I can hide specified package and classes but still don't know how to hide specified method. I have tried some annotations like @exclude or @hide in my method but the result is build failed. Kindly advise, since I don't want to mark my method as @deprecated.

Please find below my gradle configuration so far for generate javadoc and thank you for any kind help

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    // title = ''
    // description = ''
    source = variant.javaCompile.source
    classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, project.android.getBootClasspath())
    destinationDir = file("../javadoc/")
    options {
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
        linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    }
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
    exclude '**/com/green/iot/ax/lib/domain/controller/device/AirTemperatureSensorManager.java'
    exclude '**/com/green/iot/ax/lib/domain/controller/device/ButtonManager.java' 
    exclude '**/com/green/iot/ax/lib/domain/internal'
}
```

}

Comment: ...Don't make it Javadoc?

Comment: Hi Makoto, thanks but I need to make documentation without expose that method :)

Comment: There's no native way to do this.  The only options you'd have are to either not use Javadoc for that method, make the class package-private, or note in the Javadoc itself that the method is not meant for public use.

Comment: Hmm..okie then, thank you :)